# Making a method multithreaded while returning a value

Tags: java, multithreading

In my code I need to make "getResult" multithreaded.

Class X

```
public x() {
    }

public String[] getResult(params) {
//various actions to generate result
}
```

Class A

```
    X = new X();
    String[] getResult = X.getResult(params);
```

So I make class X runnable & have a run method.

But do I move the call to getResult into the run method?...and then have class A create a new instance of X passing in the params.

When I do this I can't have the run method return anything. So this is obviously wrong.

Can someone help me. Do I just need to make the class callable? Or am I going about things completely wrong?

Comment: Do you want to make the method thread-safe, to be precise?

Comment: Do you want to start a fixed number of threads or does it depend on the arguments?

Comment: Early on in the code there is a specific limit on the number of threads that can be created, so here I don't think it matters how many times "getResult" is called.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need separate (potentially inner) classes that `implement Runnable` for each separate piece of functionality required.

Instances of those classes will need to be created and started in your `getResult` method.

You'll need to use `Thread.join` to have `getResult` wait around until each thread has finished and collate the results.

Comment: Thanks for the response. There are some legacy classes that implement Runnable that I could extend. So X.getResult creates instance of Y which is runnable......If using this way, what would I actually put in the run meothd? Would it be empty? Is this unsafe? Potential CPU issues?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ThreadLocal, it will fit in to your requirement.
ThredLocal will take X as parameter and then all threads can have their thread local.

Answer (score 0):

> When I do this I can't have the run method return anything. So this is obviously wrong.

This is not entirely correct. You can return value even from run() method. You can return a value by updating class level attribute.

```
 public void run(){
   //update class attribute here.. using setter method  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple ways to get values returned from `Thread`/`Runnable` run method, store returned value in a global variable, use `Callable` etc. Below approach uses `Callable`.

```
void asyncRun(final String[] params)
        {
            ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(); //or initialize it before
            Future<String[]> f = es.submit(new Callable<String[]>() {
                public String[] call() throws Exception {
                 X = new X();
                 String[] getResult = X.getResult(params);
                 return getResult;              
                }
            });
            // below get call is blocking, you might return Future (f) itself and use it separately
            try {
                String[] val = f.get(); // or have a time out
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // handle exceptions
            }
        }
```

You question seems like you want to execute `getParams` in a thread but needs its result when it completes, this more sounds like synchronous approach though.

Comment: Might be wrong but doesn't synchronous just make it thread safe not thread runnable? I don't really need the code to thread safe (executed one at a time), I just need it to be called multiple times for increased performance.